# Is it possible to set height 100% in one .css file but should not fill div for particular page

Tags: html, css

I have so many HTML pages that share the same CSS file. All HTML pages have sidebars with different content. But the sidebar has the same properties for all.

```
#sidebar {
    min-width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 0;
    right: 15px;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

The HTML page which has long content in sidebar the `div` should scroll, that's why I set `height:100%;`.

The problem is the page which has shorter content is also filling the full `div` with empty space with white color background.

Is there any way to not to fill full div for some pages (`height:auto;`) using common CSS file?

Parent `html` does not have `height` property.

**Update:**

I am using twig templates in my html pages..I have one parent page `base.html` which extends to other pages.

The div for sidebar is in `base.html` ,so I could not give separate class for one file.

Sorry for updating now.

Comment: You could just give some class to the sidebars you need to set the height auto. Or you coud use flexbox http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback .

Comment: How about good ol' `max-height: 100%`?

Comment: xD ahahaha @Boldewyn

Comment: Please see updated quetion

Comment: @Boldewyn,max-height 100% is working.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In css this is done by overriding the stylerule like so:

```
#sidebar {
  height: auto;
}
```

This stylerule should be added only to the pages you want this height-property to differ from the default 100%. So the endresult is that by default #sidebar has height 100% and on some pages it's overwritten to be auto.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add an extra class to your CSS file, e.g. `#sidebar.auto-height{ height:auto; }` and then on the pages where you want it to apply, the HTML element should look like this: `<div id="sidebar" class="auto-height"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a style to that particular page ? Either on body or on sidebar.

```
<body class="limitheight">
```

Then : `.limitheight #sidebar {height: auto;}`

Else you can do it in a `<style>#sidebar {height: auto;}</style>` on that particular page.

If you use a CMS, pages all have a class with their num-ID, find it and replace .limitheight with the id of your page ! ;)